# Makefile not Linking Properly

Tags: linux, makefile

I was trying to follow the architecture lab for the book CS:APP, but I am getting an error and am not sure how to fix it. I get the follow error when I attempt to run make in the sim directory.

```
gcc - Wall -02 yas-grammar.o yas.o isa.o -lfl -o yas /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfl.
```

Does anyone know what this -lfl means and where I can tell the link to find it?

Comment: `-l` means "link a library", named `fl`. You need to install it somehow, probably from your package manager.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't know of any program named fl, is there a way to go about solving this? There is nothing in the lab write up that mentions this.

Comment: Search the list of packages available in your package manager. In my ubuntu I have `libfl-dev`, which looks related to [Flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(lexical_analyser_generator)), which is probably what you're after.

Comment: Search libfl.so  https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libfl.so ..... or use `apt-file search libfl.so`

Comment: Thank you! Ya I guess I needed flex and bison :)